# Missing artifact io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager

Tags: xml, maven, selenium, webdrivermanager-java

I have created one maven project and added webdrivermager from bonigarcia in the pom.xml. It is giving me the error **missing artifact io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager.**

I tried cleaning the .m2 folder and then downloading all the dependencies again. But the webdrivermanager dependency is not getting added.
Below is my pom.xml file. I also tried changing the versions.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>SeleniumFramework</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumFramework</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
 <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.12</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> 

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager -->
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency> 
</dependencies>
</project>
```

and below is my source code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class BrowserTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://selenium.dev/");
        driver.quit();  
    }   
}
```

I'm getting this error after doing a **maven install**
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

More description of the error:

```
*[WARNING] The POM for io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:jar:3.8.1 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.563 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-05T11:56:49+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project SeleniumFramework: Could not resolve dependencies for project SeleniumFramework:SeleniumFramework:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find io.github.bonigarcia:webdrivermanager:jar:3.8.1 in <one of the url> was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of repository has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.*
```

Comment: This issue is solved now as we have to add the url of global maven repository in the settings.xml file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is solved now as we have to add the **URL** of the **global** maven repository in the settings.xml file.